# Event Handler in C# does not convert correctly to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

Here is the Interface

```vb
Public Interface ILoginConductor
    Inherits IHandle(Of LoginEvent)
    Inherits IHandle(Of LogoutEvent)
    Inherits IHandle(Of ExitEvent)
End Interface
```

In C# here is the method that uses the interface

```cs
public void Handle(LoginEvent message)
{
    LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
    loginWindow.Login += new EventHandler<LoginEventArgs>(this.LoginWindow_Login);
    loginWindow.Cancel += new EventHandler(LoginWindow_Cancel);
    loginWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

And it converts to this in VB.Net

```vb
Public Sub Handle(message As LoginEvent) Implements    ILoginConductor.Handle
    Dim loginWindow As New LoginWindow()
    loginWindow.Login += New EventHandler(Of LoginEventArgs)(AddressOf Me.LoginWindow_Login)
    loginWindow.Cancel += New EventHandler(AddressOf LoginWindow_Cancel)
    loginWindow.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

But the compiler throws a error which says that I must use a `RaiseEvent`.  Could someone please help me to show me how to fix my code.

Comment: What do you mean "converts to"? Are you using a conversion tool? If so, which one? The issue is because VB doesn't have the += operator. You instead need to use the [RaiseEvent statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx).

Comment: @Clint : The VB.NET equivalent of `+=` is infact the [**AddHandler statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx), not RaiseEvent.

Comment: @VisualVincent that it does! Silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the compiler tells you that the events in the VB code must be triggered in a different way than C# does. You need to perpend the "raiseevent" keyword before the event method call (eg raiseevent Login_WindowCancel()). Take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx

Comment: The compiler interprets it incorrectly. The actual equivalent of `+=` in this case is the [**AddHandler statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx).

Comment: Also see [**How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still troubled.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still troubled.

Comment: While I am familiar with the use of RaiseEvent the link above to subscribing unfortunately does not have a VB equivalent.  A simple example of addhandler to the original code sample would do the trick.

Comment: I finally found the correct syntax

Comment: RaiseEvent(AddHandler New EventHandler(Of LoginEventArgs)(AddressOf Me.LoginWindow_Login)
            RaiseEvent(AddHandler New EventHandler(AddressOf LoginWindow_Cancel)

Comment: Problem still is not solved.  I Still have the wrong syntax in my example above, so need a VB expert here to show me what to do.